# Unable to start elasticsearch

Tags: linux, process, aws, elasticsearch

Configuration :
Elasticsearch Version = 5.0.1
OS = Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03

I am using AWS m3.large instance. I have two elasticsearch nodes. For my data node(node-2) , When I started elasticsearch service with

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

I found this as the error log.

```
[2016-11-25T09:31:56,884][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [node-2] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2016-11-25T09:31:56,886][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node-2] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
```

Then I edited file  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service` and added line

```
LimitNPROC=2048
```

When I restarted service. I checked status:

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

It returned,

```
elasticsearch dead but subsys locked
```

In Log

```
[2016-11-25T09:50:32,138][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [node-2] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2016-11-25T09:50:32,140][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node-2] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
```

The output of

```
[ec2-user@ip-address]$ ls -la /var/lock/subsys
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 09:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 root lock 4096 Nov 25 03:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:10 atd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 auditd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 blk-availability
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:10 crond
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 25 09:50 elasticsearch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:10 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:07 lvm2-monitor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 messagebus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 netfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 network
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:34 ntpd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:09 ntpdate
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:08 rsyslog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 18 05:07 salt-minion
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:10 sendmail
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:10 sm-client
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  9 19:09 sshd
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please add to the post `ls -la /var/lock/subsys`

Comment: Please check updated question @RuiFRibeiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my Amazon Linux(2014.03) to Amazon Linux(2016.09). Now elasticsearch is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t start `elasticsearch` because a dangling lock file is present in the system.

It is sufficient to delete it with:

```
sudo rm /var/lock/subsys/elasticsearch
```

Then you will be able to start `elasticsearch` again.

If this happens regularly, I would advise investigating the reasons behind it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you suggested and got following output.
` 
    [ec2-user@subsys]$ sudo rm elasticsearch 
    [ec2-user@subsys]$ sudo service elasticsearch status
    elasticsearch is stopped
    [ec2-user@subsys]$ sudo service elasticsearch start
    Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
    [ec2-user@subsys]$ sudo service elasticsearch status
    elasticsearch (pid  32500) is running...
    [ec2-user@]$ sudo service elasticsearch status
    elasticsearch dead but subsys locked
`

Comment: Apologize for bad formatting @RuiFRiberio. As per your answer I got same output as previous comment.

Comment: do the * rm*. again, then  `ulimit -u 2048`
. as root, then start it.

Comment: I got this output @RuiFRiberio `[root@subsys]# rm elasticsearch 
    rm: remove regular empty file ‘elasticsearch’? 
    [root@subsys]# ulimit -u 2048
    [root@]# sudo service elasticsearch status
    elasticsearch dead but subsys locked
    [root@subsys]# sudo service elasticsearch stop
    [root@subsys]# sudo service elasticsearch start
    Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
    [root@subsys]# sudo service elasticsearch status
    elasticsearch dead but subsys locked
    [root@subsys]#`

Comment: I upgraded my Amazon Linux(2014.03) to Amazon linux (2016.09). Now elasticsearch is working fine.

Comment: I suggest you add an answer to your own question, then I will delete this answer.